# Is there a good way to implement Objection/Sequelize on an existing database?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, objection.js

I have an existing database with 10 or so tables and thousands of rows. I’m tiring of SQL and would like to add an ORM — probably either Objection or Sequelize.

Is there a good way to implement either ORM on an existing database?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not particularly difficult to connect Sequelize to an existing database. You just need to configure the connection and set up models.

If your previously-created tables include some attributes that don't match up to Sequelize's approach out of the box, you may need to write some extra code in your models. Again, this is fairly painless. See [Working With Legacy Tables](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/legacy/) for additional information.